# mysql join and count

Tags: mysql

Somehow am not successful with creating the query that I want.

DB is to do with locations, there are the following tables which are relevant

- `t_location` - list of locations incl. field `t_location_zipcode`, and `t_location_id_location`
- `t_zipcodecity` - join table just t_zipcodecity_zipcode   t_zipcodecity_id_city
- `t_city` - city list with `t_city_id_city`
- `t_citystate` - join table, t_citystate_id_city, t_citystate_id_state
- `t_state` - list of states with t_state_id_state

Initially I tried to get a list of states with locations using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t_state_id_state`
      , `t_state_name_full` 
  FROM (`t_state`) 
LEFT JOIN `t_citystate` ON `t_state_id_state` = `t_citystate_id_state` 
LEFT JOIN `t_city` ON `t_citystate_id_state` = `t_city_id_city` 
LEFT JOIN `t_zipcodecity` ON `t_city_id_city` = `t_zipcodecity_id_city` 
LEFT JOIN `t_location` ON `t_zipcodecity_zipcode` = `t_location_zipcode` 
ORDER BY `t_state_name_full` asc ­
```

which works fine.

Now what I also need / want which I am failing dismally at is to get the number of locations in each state. I don't know if it can be done in this one query or if i need another, either way I need help!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there is a many-to-many relationship between `City` and `State` and another many-to-many relationship between `City` and `Location`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  t_state_id_state
      , t_state_name_full 
      , COUNT(DISTINCT t_location_id_location) AS locations_number

  FROM 
        t_state
    LEFT JOIN 
        t_citystate   ON t_state_id_state = t_citystate_id_state 
    LEFT JOIN 
        t_city   ON t_citystate_id_state = t_city_id_city 
    LEFT JOIN 
        t_zipcodecity   ON t_city_id_city = t_zipcodecity_id_city 
    LEFT JOIN 
        t_location   ON t_zipcodecity_zipcode = t_location_zipcode 

  GROUP BY t_state_id_state 

  ORDER BY t_state_name_full ASC ­
```

Comment: Ok thats looking good, my fault with the left joins, i was initially trying to get ALL the states which is why i used them. But i change that to use inner joins
`code`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a count and a group by.  Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t_state_id_state`
          , `t_state_name_full`
          , COUNT(*) 
      FROM (`t_state`) 
 LEFT JOIN `t_citystate` ON `t_state_id_state` = `t_citystate_id_state` 
 LEFT JOIN `t_city` ON `t_citystate_id_state` = `t_city_id_city` 
 LEFT JOIN `t_zipcodecity` ON `t_city_id_city` = `t_zipcodecity_id_city` 
 LEFT JOIN `t_location` ON `t_zipcodecity_zipcode` = `t_location_zipcode` 
  GROUP BY `t_state_id_state` , `t_state_name_full`
  ORDER BY `t_state_name_full` asc
```

Comment: that's not exactly it, the results are definitely wrong.
Complete Total is much too high, and so are some of the numbers of locations per state (some too high, some too low)

Comment: I would suggest then to start by removing all the LEFT JOINS and getting a count, making sure it is correct, then adding one at a time.  It may be that you have bad data, or data you were not expecting.  For example, more than one citystate_id for one city.

Comment: i understand what you mean in principle but....
if i just use SELECT DISTINCT `t_state_id_state`, `t_state_name_full`, COUNT(*) FROM (`t_state`) - i get 1 state and a total number of states

Answer (score 0):

Ok thats looking good, my bad with the left joins, i was initially trying to get ALL the states which is why i used them. But i change that to use inner joins

```
SELECT  t_state_id_state,
t_state_name_full,
COUNT(DISTINCT t_location_id_location) AS locations_number
FROM t_state
INNER JOIN t_citystate ON t_citystate_id_state = t_state_id_state 
INNER JOIN t_city ON t_city_id_city = t_citystate_id_city 
INNER JOIN t_zipcodecity ON t_zipcodecity_id_city = t_city_id_city 
INNER JOIN t_location ON t_location_zipcode = t_zipcodecity_zipcode 
GROUP BY t_state_id_state 
ORDER BY t_state_name_full ASC
```

then i actually end up with a result that looks good !